# MySQL Order By Title then Grouped ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table which contains tasks that can be grouped by a task.

I am wondering if there is a way to select the tasks from the table with an order that puts child tasks ordered by title directly under their parents, which are ordered by title. There would only ever be one layer of child nodes (i.e. no row could have a parent that isn't at the top level)

Below is an example table and fiddle. With this example, the desired output would be:

```
TaskID ParentTaskID Title
----------------------------------
6      NULL         A Task 3
1      NULL         Task 1
7      1            Task 1 A Sub 3
3      1            Task 1 Sub 1
4      1            Task 1 Sub 2
2      NULL         Task 2
5      2            Task 2 Sub 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79c9d2/1)

```
CREATE TABLE `Tasks` (
  `TaskID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ParentTaskID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(254) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `Tasks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`TaskID`);

ALTER TABLE `Tasks`
  MODIFY `TaskID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

  INSERT INTO `Tasks` (`TaskID`, `ParentTaskID`, `Title`) VALUES ('1', NULL, 'Task 1'), ('2', NULL, 'Task 2'), ('3', '1', 'Task 1 Sub 1'), ('4', '1', 'Task 1 Sub 2'), ('5', '2', 'Task 2 Sub 1'), ('6', NULL, 'A Task 3'), ('7', '1', 'Task 1 A Sub 3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first order make sure Task and Child are group together, then the nulls (parents) would be first, and finally the childs will be sort by title

[**SQL DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93b7757479d4f5f0ee4d6d65693d5976)

```
SELECT p.*, c.* 
FROM Tasks as p
JOIN Tasks as c
 ON c.ParentTaskID = p.TaskID
 OR (c.ParentTaskID IS NULL and p.TaskID = c.TaskID)
ORDER BY p.Title
       , c.ParentTaskID
       , c.Title;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+--------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+----------------+
| TaskID | ParentTaskID |  Title   | TaskID | ParentTaskID |     Title      |
+--------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+----------------+
|      6 |              | A Task 3 |      6 |              | A Task 3       |
|      1 |              | Task 1   |      1 |              | Task 1         |
|      1 |              | Task 1   |      7 |            1 | Task 1 A Sub 3 |
|      1 |              | Task 1   |      3 |            1 | Task 1 Sub 1   |
|      1 |              | Task 1   |      4 |            1 | Task 1 Sub 2   |
|      2 |              | Task 2   |      2 |              | Task 2         |
|      2 |              | Task 2   |      5 |            2 | Task 2 Sub 1   |
+--------+--------------+----------+--------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I changed it to `ORDER BY Title, COALESCE(ParentTaskID, TaskID)
       , ParentTaskID
       , Title` to have the top level tasks ordered by title as well.

Comment: Good. I saw that requirement after finish my answer and wasnt sure how solve it.

Comment: Actually that didn't solve it, it only coincidentally solved it for the example dataset :(

Comment: Sorry, That only work because all the title beside the first are 'Task...'  change anyone and won't work. I don't think you can do the exact requirement you want. I will think about it but doesn't seem easy.

Comment: I did it. I use a self join to assign the child the same title as the parent. So can sort by parent title first. Modesty apart, I'm so good sometimes scare me :)

Comment: Sweet! I think I'm correct in saying that it only needs to be `SELECT c.* ...` to get all the details, right?

Comment: Yes, I leave parent info for debug propose

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can do this using window functions in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tasks
ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN ParentTaskId IS NULL THEN Title END) OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(ParentTaskId, TaskId)),  -- parent title
         COALESCE(ParentTaskId, TaskId),  -- parent id in case titles match
         (ParentTaskId IS NULL) DESC,     -- parent first
         Title;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=163cbcbfc3bb403818c344b407b9ea2d) is a db<>fiddle.